# unable to install ubuntu

Tags: installation

I am working on my HP laptop with Windows7. I am not able to install ubuntu (making it dual boot). I have made my usb stick bootable by using UNETBOOTIN. Following are the steps I took to install ubuntu:

Bios device options->my_usbstick->default.

after this nothing else happens. just a blank screen persists until I have to eventually shut down my system. I assure that the iso file used is good as with the same procedure followed my friend was able to install ubuntu in his DELL system.
Please help me out with this one.

Comment: Some laptops require you press a key or key combination at boot to be able to boot from USB. On my Dell I press F12 and I get the option to boot from CD and from USB. Also be sure you got the iso for your achitecture (x86, 64 bit, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Due to some issues with 'X' upstream, booting Ubuntu from CD/USB on some graphics cards (mostly Nvidia and ATI) results in a black screen or a weird display with horizontal or vertical lines. Just as if there is no display output from the graphics card, or the resolution is not being read by the monitor. Actually, there is an output, but it is out of sync. In order to solve this, you need to pass the nomodeset boot parameter, or some other parameters listed at the end of this guide.

Live CD/USB Environment

Pop in your CD/USB and boot from it. As soon as the computer starts booting from the boot media, keep on pressing any key until you are presented with this page:

Once you see this page, press F6 and you'll see some boot options popping up. Navigate to the "nomodeset" entry and hit Enter. You'll see a mark in the beginning. Press  and now choose "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" or "Install Ubuntu", whichever you want.

Hopefully, you'll see the desktop this time.